# How can I correct this query that involves a CASE statement for a summary?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to solve an issue revolving around summarizing a list of publishers, their total revenue, total payouts, and their net profit. What makes this slightly complicated is that the total payout is contingent on a case statement (due to having to choose between the higher value of royalties). This case statement was perfectly fine and executed in a previous query that you can see on the SQLFiddle link down below. My issue is that I have a near finished query that addresses what I need but I don't know what correction to make for it to complete. Help would be super appreciated! And if you get it to work, you would be a legit lifesaver!!

```
 Select name,
SUM(book.msrp) AS 'Total Revenue',
SUM(EarningByBook) AS 'Total Payouts',
SUM(book.msrp)-SUM(EarningByBook) AS 'Net Profit'
FROM
(SELECT publisher.name, book.msrp,
(SELECT 
       CASE WHEN preferred_royalties > standard_royalties
                THEN preferred_royalties*copies_sold
                ELSE standard_royalties*copies_sold END 
       AS 'EarningByBook', 
       copies_sold , 
       YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(date_published) Years
INNER JOIN book ON publisher.id = book.publisher_id)
FROM author A 
JOIN book B ON A.id=B.author_id 
JOIN publisher P ON B.publisher_id=P.id)
From publisher
INNER JOIN book ON publisher.id = book.publisher_id) Z
GROUP BY 
 name;
```

The SQL fiddle is as follows :
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b0015a0a4286f9b2c064bbd65525faa5&hide=13312

The output expected should look

| Publisher | Total Revenue | Total Payouts | Net Profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name | 20000 | 1500 | 18500 |
| name | 15000 | 1000 | 14000 |

Comment: Welcome to SO, Theodocius! What is the error you get? A message or a wrong result? I think it's an error message. It strikes me that you innermost SELECT statement has no FROM clouse.

Comment: @h.m.i.13 I got the following error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT publisher.name, book.msrp 
From publisher 
INNER JOIN book ON publisher.i' at line 17"

Comment: @h.m.i.13 , the issue is that I'm not really sure how to rearrange and reorder it so that it flows properly :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider flattening all your inner selects to a single `SELECT` subquery.

```sql
SELECT sub.publisher
     , SUM(sub.msrp) AS 'Total Revenue'
     , SUM(sub.EarningByBook) AS 'Total Payouts'
     , SUM(sub.msrp) - SUM(sub.EarningByBook) AS 'Net Profit'
FROM
  (SELECT 
        P.`name` AS publisher
      , CASE 
          WHEN A.preferred_royalties > P.standard_royalties
          THEN A.preferred_royalties * B.copies_sold
          ELSE P.standard_royalties * B.copies_sold 
        END AS EarningByBook
     , YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(B.date_published) AS Years
     , B.msrp
     , B.copies_sold
     
  FROM author A 
  INNER JOIN book B 
     ON A.id = B.author_id 
  INNER JOIN publisher P 
     ON B.publisher_id = P.id
  ) AS sub
  
GROUP BY 
  sub.publisher;
```